# How to retrieve CC email address from MS outlook 2010?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2010

I am using below code to retrieve the different mail parameter from MS outlook 2010. but I am not able to get CC email address. `CC` property of `MailItem` class is returning Name, not email address.

```
            NameSpace _nameSpace;
            ApplicationClass _app;
            _app = new ApplicationClass();
            _nameSpace = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            object o = _nameSpace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection);
            MailItem Item = (MailItem)o;
            string HTMLbpdyTest = Item.HTMLBody;
            CreationTime = Convert.ToString(Item.CreationTime);
            strEmailSenderEmailIdMAPI = Convert.ToString(Item.SenderEmailAddress);
            strEmailSenderName = Item.SenderName;
            Subject = Item.Subject;
            string CCEmailAddress = Item.CC;
```

Please suggest, how can I get CC email addresses?

Answer (score 6):

Loop through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and for each `Recipient` object check its `Type` property; `OlMailRecipientType.olCC` is what you want. You can then read the `Recipient.Address` property.

EDIT: Off the top of my head.

```
foreach (Recipient recip in Item.Recipients)
{
  if (recip.Type == OlMailRecipientType.olCC)
  {
    if (CCEmailAddress.length > 0) CCEmailAddress += ";";
    CCEmailAddress += recip.Address;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code for this? I am trying but not able achieve.

Comment: if (recip.Type == OlMailRecipientType.olCC) gives error - Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMailRecipientType'

Comment: You need to cast either the left side to OlMailRecipientType or the right side to int. Or, since olCC is 2, just compare Recipient.Type to 2.

Comment: thnx.. but now I am getting email address like this - /O=EXG5/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=Test88067

Comment: This is a perfectly valid EX address. If you want the SMTP address, use Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrmarySmtpAddress.

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by @Dmitry's answer and tried a few things on my own to have these lines of code fix my problems and give me an array of the cc-ed addresses that are present in a given mail item.

```
public string[] GetCCAddress(MailItem mailItem)
    {
        string email;
        Outlook.ExchangeUser exUser;
        List <string> ccEmailAddressList = new List<string>();
        foreach (Recipient recip in mailItem.Recipients)
        {
            if ((OlMailRecipientType)recip.Type == OlMailRecipientType.olCC)
            {
                    email=recip.Address;
                    if (!email.Contains("@"))
                    {
                        exUser = recip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                        email = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                    }
                    ccEmailAddressList.Add(email);

            }
        }
```

This statement `if (!email.Contains("@"))` is to avoid calling `exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` on an actual email address and restrict that to entries such as " /O=EXG5/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=Test88067"

Comment: You be better off retrieving the PR_ADDRTYPE property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3002001F`) using Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty and checking whether it is "EX".

Comment: I followed your advice. Thanks.

Comment: You might also check that recip.AddressEntry and AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser are not null.

Comment: How could it be null if it already is an EX type in the cc field ?

Comment: 1. The message was copied from an Exchange mailbox to a PST store and that PST store opened in a profile without the original Exchange server. 2., The Server or network is down and GAL cannot be contacted.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static int ConnectToOutlook()
{
    try
    {
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
        oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);                        
        Outlook.MAPIFolder oInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent;                              
        List<string> ccRecipient = new List<string>();
        foreach (MAPIFolder folder in oInbox.Folders)
        {
            if (folder.FullFolderPath.Contains("Inbox"))
            {
                foreach (MAPIFolder subFolder in folder.Folders)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (subFolder.FullFolderPath.Contains("Folder Name Inside Inbox"))
                        {
                            foreach (object folderItems in subFolder.Items)
                            {
                                if (folderItems is Outlook.MailItem)
                                {
                                    Outlook.MailItem email_Msg = (Outlook.MailItem)folderItems;
                                    Console.WriteLine("Subject=>" + email_Msg.Subject);
                                    //Console.WriteLine("From=>" + email_Msg.SenderEmailAddress);
                                    //Console.WriteLine("Cc=>" + email_Msg.CC);
                                    //Console.WriteLine("Recipients=>" + email_Msg.Recipients[1].Address);
                                    foreach (Recipient recipient in email_Msg.Recipients)
                                    {
                                        if ((OlMailRecipientType)recipient.Type == OlMailRecipientType.olCC)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("Cc=>" + recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress);                                                                                                      
                                        }

                                    }                                           
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }               
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught: ", e);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Item.CC.Address
```

or

```
((MailAddress)Item.CC).Address
```